# Here API - Places search by tag

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to search by a tag?

The documentation lets me search by category (restaurant, eat-drink, food-drink), but I'm looking for something more granular (pizza, ice cream, sandwiches).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do not have a specific search field for "tag".You can search for a "tag" in the same way as for "category". For example, if you want to search for "pizza" at=41.8459,-87.9428. You can get all the restaurants/eateries where category is tagged as "pizza" places.You will have to use method /places/v1/discover/search

```
    curl \
  --compressed \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding:gzip' \
  -H 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5' \
  --get 'http://places.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code=<app_code>' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id=<app_id>' \
    --data-urlencode 'at=41.8282,-87.8029' \
    --data-urlencode 'cs=pds' \
    --data-urlencode 'pretty=true' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=pizza' \
    --data-urlencode 'size=20'
```